# Raise an error on a field based on a ForeignKey field of the model DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Thanks for your time:

i've got a model to get more user information by OneToOneField and the username becomes the Pets.pessoa field when saving it

bascally i'd like to raise an error if the foreignkey field(Pets.pessoa) starts with 'a' and Pets.tipo == 2

i'm getting the object created even when the error should appear

Models.py:

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='person')
    birthday = models.DateField()
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user)


class Pets(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    tipo = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.pessoa, self.nome)
```

Forms.py:

```
class PetForm3(forms.ModelForm): #SELECIONAR FORM PELO FORMS.PY
    field_choices = [
        (1, 'CACHORRO'),
        (2, 'GATO'),
        (3, 'OUTRO')
    ]

    nome = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    custo = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    tipo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=field_choices)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pessoa_data = self.cleaned_data.get('pessoa')
        pessoa_string = slugify(pessoa_data)
        tipo_data = self.cleaned_data.get('tipo')
        if pessoa_string.startswith('a') and tipo_data==2:
            raise ValidationError('User começando com A não pode ter gato')
        return super(PetForm3, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Views.py:

```
def create_pet_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PetForm3(request.POST)
        pet = form.save(commit=False)
        pet.pessoa = request.user.person
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PetForm3()
    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    return render(request, 'petform3.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_pet_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PetForm3(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pet = form.save(commit=False)
            pet.pessoa = request.user.person
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PetForm3()
    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    return render(request, 'petform3.html', context)
```

if this work

Comment: thats how a render the normal form but i want to set a ValidationError if Pets.pessoa.startswith('a') and Pets.tipo == 2